# What should my windows application implement to accomplish a Scheduling Job on a frequency?

Tags: windows, msmq, nservicebus

My requirement in brief:
I need a to generate xml data(max of 500KB) which will be posted via FTP or HTTP to a specified end point on scheduled intervals like weekly daily or hourly .These data is something more specific to a customer who sets his required sceduling frequency.My customers number might limit to 20 max.

Sol:
Initially I thought it can be just a windows service run on a scheduler job evry minute ,but want to know if it would be efficient if I use MSMQ or N-service Bus or a windows Bus.I am new to these technologies so not sure when they are really suite dto my requirement, can someone let me know when do we go for MSMQ and N-servie Bus. Does my requirement suit any of these?

Comment: Typically a service bus would not provide scheduling functionality in its core but it is something that can easily be added.  A couple of years ago I did this on NServiceBus but I no longer have that code.  I have implemented the basics on my shuttle-esb FOSS here: https://github.com/Shuttle/shuttle-scheduling but it hasn't been looked at for a while (time and so on).  It may give you some ideas and can easily be adapted to any service bus.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like NServiceBus can do the job and help you with [scheduling](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/scheduling-with-nservicebus) and [posting over http](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/introduction-to-the-gateway). also [sagas](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas-in-nservicebus) can help you with long running interactions and state tracking.

HTH